# Keenetic Lite WiFi speed

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I have a Keenetic Lite Rev.A router (with latest firmware, ver. ~2.0). My wired Internet connection is about 70mbps, but when I connect via WiFi om my Mac I get only about 40-45 mbps (on another laptop with Win8 it get about 25-30, btw why it's less?). WiFi standard is set to "GN".
Is this wifi speed normal?

Comment: Have you tried *N only*?

Answer (score 0):

That router only supports a single spatial stream (1x1) and only supports the 2.4GHz band, which is also used by Bluetooth and other users. To get the advertised 150Mbps signaling rate, it must be configured to use 40MHz-wide channels instead of the traditional 20MHz-wide channels used by Wi-Fi in the 2.4GHz band in the past. 40MHz-wide channels don't leave much room for other users of the band, such as Bluetooth and other Wi-Fi devices.

Apple cares about preserving some 2.4GHz bandwidth for Bluetooth devices, so Apple's Wi-Fi devices limit themselves to traditional 20MHz-wide channels in the 2.4GHz band. So your Mac's maximum signaling rate to that router is limited to 72.2Mbps.

On top of that, Wi-Fi is fairly inefficient, so your TCP over IPv4 throughput over Wi-Fi is often just 50-80% of your signaling rate. So your 40-45Mbps rate sounds about right. For best results, use a local performance tool like IPerf, between a Gigabit Ethernet machine on LAN and your wireless client. Make sure to specify `-w 2M` on both ends of the IPerf session to make sure you've got a big enough TCP window.

My first guess for why your Windows box got just 25-30Mbps is that it guessed a too-small TCP window size and didn't auto-tune it correctly. Playing with the window size you give IPerf could tell you that. Either that or your Windows box is farther away from your Wi-Fi router and is getting a lower signaling rate.

By the way, leave your Wi-Fi standard set to GN or BGN. It doesn't hurt anything, and in fact it helps your range by allowing your clients to fall back to G or B rates when they're too far away for N rates. But for best results, try to upgrade all of your Wi-Fi clients to 802.11n; try not to have B or G clients on the network (or on an overlapping network).